# Class that can hold Strings or Integers in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I'm creating a Table class that uses an ArrayList of ArrayLists, and when the user instantiates the class, I want them to be able to create a table of Strings or ints. Do I accomplish this with generics?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is what generics does. For instance you could create your table class like follows:

```
public class Table<K> {
    public List<List<K>> list;
}
```

The user can then create an intance:

```
Table<String> tableOfStrings = new Table<String>();
Table<Integer> tableOfIntegers = new Table<Integer>();
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Can you update your answer with some examples of how to manipulate the columns/rows? I think that's the last hurdle I need to jump before I can picture how the ArrayList table works in my head.

Comment: If you create a getter `public List<List<K>> getList()` you can manipulate the list using e.g., `myTable.getList().add(new LinkedList<String>());`

Comment: Thanks again for all your help, Johan! I should also mention that it may be important to instantiate `list` in `Table` by typing `List<List<K>> list = new List<List<K>>();` to make sure you don't get NullPointerException errors. At least that's a problem I had, ymmv.